# URL Mapping and WebMethods Error in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite/URL map my ASP.NET Web pages using [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/698666/USE-OF-MapPageRoute-Method-IN-ASP-NET-WEBFORM-ROUT). However, the problem I'm facing is, the Web Methods/PageMethods of that page doesn't get loaded/fired when I access the web page through the new URL.

**Global.asax:**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            //The code that maps the page
            RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "projects/{id}", "~/CreateProject.aspx");
}
```

**The PageMethod in the Javascript file of that Page:**

```
function loaddata() {

    PageMethods.set_path('/CreateProject.aspx');
    PageMethods.LoadProjectData(onSuccess, onFailure);

    function onSuccess(val) { }
    function onFailure() { }
}
```

As you can see, I have mapped them properly.

**Good news:** The Web page is now accessible through this link, as it should -> http://localhost:19568/projects/12320012

**Bad news:** Nothing gets loaded in that page. By nothing I mean images, scripts, etc. Here's a console screenshot

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the page and the content load properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the problem. The problem was actually very silly. Even though I don't know the reason behind this, I know how to fix the issue.

Basically I had to add the '/' back slash in front of every resource I imported to the web page. For example:

**Previously:**

```
<script src="JS/newproject.js"></script>
```

**Updated:**

```
<script src="/JS/newproject.js"></script>
```

This should be done for any images you import, css, scripts, etc. Hope it helps someone!